# scale_color_gradient2 having text be rounded

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am using `scale_fill_gradient2()` and the colourbar that is created is showing decimal places. I tried to reproduce the text that shows decimals but could not but the text below is in scientific notations.

How can you round the numbers that displayed in the colourbar using `scale_fill_gradient2()`?  For example I am seeing "25.00" and I'd like to show just "25"?

Also how can you set the labels manually?  Let's say I want to look a the data and set labels like `c(15, 25, 40)`?

```
library(ggplot2)
dat <- data.frame(group = c(rep("A", 10), rep("B", 10)),
                  value = c(rnorm(10, 5,300), rnorm(10, 5000, 80000)))

ggplot(dat, aes(x = group, y = value, fill= value)) + 
       geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
       scale_fill_gradient2(low = "red", mid = "yellow", high = "blue", midpoint = 0, name = "")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can manually specify breaks and labels as needed.

```
ggplot(dat, aes(x = group, y = value, fill= value)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity")+
  scale_fill_gradient2(low = "red", mid = "yellow", high = "blue", 
                       midpoint = 0, name = "",
                       breaks = c(0, 1e5, 2e5),
                       labels = c("0", "100,000", "200,000"))
```

[image]